# Color each row different in Pandas DataFrame using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this code:

```
tnse_mat
>>> array([[ 23.941637 ,  17.583256 ],
       [-30.239468 ,   3.5285048],
       [-23.219652 ,  14.943658 ],
       ...,
       [-53.214344 , -27.811293 ],
       [ 57.022842 ,  41.384315 ],
       [ 23.830252 ,  23.668056 ]], dtype=float32)
```

and I would like to plot each row in different color.
I have this code:

```
color_pallete = sns.color_palette("Spectral", as_cmap=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=tnse_mat, columns=["x", "y"])
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", data=df, palette=color_pallete)
```

I am getting this output:
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want literally every row to have a different color, you can set `hue=df.index` (and you'd probably want `legend=False` as well):

```py
sns.scatterplot(x="x", y="y", hue=df.index, data=df, palette=color_pallete, legend=False)
```